# Keep python script running (restart if exits)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I'm running a python script from the boot of the system (tried both init.d and systemd). If something goes wrong - it quits, writes problem in a log, but I need to restart it manually. Is there a way to do this check with native tools (e.g. not checking "ps -A" and restart)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're already using a service manager like systemd to run your script at boot, I would configure that service manager to automatically restart the script when it crashes. (This is a big part of what service managers are for!)

According to the [systemd.service](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html) man page, you can add something like this to your service file:

```
Restart=on-failure
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use a try and except block to output the error and restart the software without quitting?

```py
try:
    print("a")
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

This will stop at the first problem and call the except block. You can input a restart code inside the except block, and run the try block again.

Comment: No-no-no, there are lots of try/except in my program. Just review it as a deamon process, which must be always in the system. No matter if I "kill -15" it